# Using sed to extract morse code from a text file

Tags: unix, sed

I have an assignment to use 'sed' to extract morse code (dashes and periods) from a text file containing the following

```
A test to see if the morse code can be removed from a file. .--- -. ..
This is a test --. -.- .-- .. -.. --- .- .. of sorts and so on. Let's see if the code snippets can be found.
Also can they be .- . -.- removed and yet leave the periods at the end
of sentences alone. ---- -. There are also hyphenated words like the
following: Edgar-Jones. -.
```

Now I could use sed to remove all of the characters [a-z] and [A-Z] but the problem would be the periods at the end of sentences would get picked up as well as the hyphen in Edgar-Jones. I just can't find a way to take those out as well...

Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Thanks for all the answers, every one was helpful. This is the one I went with

```
sed "s/[a-zA-Z][-.]//g;s/[a-zA-Z: ']*//g" file
```

It finds an instance of a dash or a period that follows a character and removes that first which is what I was having trouble with. Then it goes and cleans up the rest of the characters and whitespace and colons and apostrophes.

Thanks again!

Comment: is using sed a must?

Comment: Yes unfortunately it must be done in sed

Comment: ok, I post the sed answer, other tool could be eaiser..

Comment: @EdMorton, seems pretty clear that he wants to remove the NON-morse words, but doesn't know how to remove the words that may have a dot or a dash in them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this sed one-liner should do the job :

> extract morse code (dashes and periods)

on your example file:

```
sed "s/[a-zA-Z][-.]//g;s/[a-zA-Z: ']*//g" file
```

test with your file:

```
kent$  cat f1
A test to see if the morse code can be removed from a file. .--- -. ..
This is a test --. -.- .-- .. -.. --- .- .. of sorts and so on. Let's see if the code snippets can be found.
Also can they be .- . -.- removed and yet leave the periods at the end
of sentences alone. ---- -. There are also hyphenated words like the
following: Edgar-Jones. -.

kent$  sed "s/[a-zA-Z][-.]//g;s/[a-zA-Z: ']*//g" f1
.----...
--.-.-.--..-..---.-..
.-.-.-
-----.
-.
```

Comment: @kent, how are the individual morse letters supposed to be extracted from that? Is `-.`  "N" or "TE"? I suggest you remove the space from the 2nd regex.

Comment: @glennjackman I thought the spaces should be removed `extract morse code (dashes and periods)`

Answer (score 1):

Here is an `awk` to can fix this.

```
awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i!~/[a-zA-Z0-9]/) printf "%s ",$i;print ""}' file
.--- -. ..
--. -.- .-- .. -.. --- .- ..
.- . -.-
---- -.
-.
```

This test every field, and if it contains `a-z` do not print it.

Or as Glenn commented:

```
awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i~/^[.-]+$/) printf "%s ",$i;print ""}' file
```

Comment: You want a positive assertion: `if ($i ~ /^[.-]+$/)` -- your current regex will let numbers pass through.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed 's/\(^\|[[:blank:]]\)[^[:blank:]]*[^-.[:blank:]][^[:blank:]]*/ /g' file
```

```
               .--- -. ..
     --. -.- .-- .. -.. --- .- ..              
     .- . -.-         
    ---- -.       
   -.
```

That regular expression is:

- the beginning of the line, or a space
- some non-whitespace chars
- followed by a character that is not whitespace or a morse character
- followed by some non-whitespace characters

This identifies words that have at least one non-morse character in them, and then replaces them with a single space.

Simpler with GNU grep, too bad you can't use it:

```
grep -oP '(?<=^|\s)[.-]+(?=\s|$)' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/\.$//
     s/\([^-[:space:].]\{1,\}[-.]\{0,1\}\)*//g
     s/\([[:space:]]\)\{2,\}/\1/g
     ' YourFile
```

- replace multispace by 1
- posix version